# PHP- How to add html table cell values to MYSQL Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

First of all I have an empty table(First, it only contain table headings)and 4 Input fields.if someone fill those 4 input fields and press `Add medicine` Button; the values of those 4 input fields come as first row of the table. if it  done again the second row of the table will be filed up.
This table contain 5th column which has a button to delete corresponding row.
**i want to tell that those two button are working perfectly.**
What i really want is, if some one finishes the row adding; all the row values should go to the database as rows.
please guide me to do this.

**add_prescrition.php**

```
<form method="POST" >
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="fullName">Appointment Number</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="text" name="appNumber" id="appNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Appointment Number" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="nic">Patient's Name</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="text" name="pName" id="pName" class="form-control" placeholder="Patinet's Name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="nic">Patient's Age</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="text" name="pAge" id="pAge" class="form-control" placeholder="Patient's Age">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <!-- Multiple CKEditor -->
    <label for="nic">Present Complaint</label>
        <textarea name="pc" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            CKEDITOR.add            
        </script>
        <br><br>
    <label for="nic">Examination</label>
    <textarea name="examination" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2' );
            CKEDITOR.add            
        </script>
</div>

<label for="Treatment"><h4>Treatment</h4></label>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="doctorName">Drug Name</label>
            <select id="drugId" class="form-control show-tick" data-live-search="true" name="drugId" id="doctorId">
                <option value="0"> Select Drug</option>
                 <?php $ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * from doctors");
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret))
                {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']);?>">
                    <?php echo htmlentities($row['doctorName']);?>
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="nic">Dose</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                 <input type="text" name="dose" id="dose" class="form-control" placeholder="Eg: 1+0+1  2+0+2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="nic">Days</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                 <input type="text" name="days" id="days" class="form-control" placeholder="Eg: 1, 2, 5">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="nic">External Medicine</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                <textarea rows="1" class="form-control no-resize auto-growth" placeholder="External Medicine" id="eMedicine"></textarea>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success m-t-10 waves-effect" onclick="addRow();" value="Add Medicine">
<div class="body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable js-exportable" name="drugTable" id="drugTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Drug Name</th>
                    <th>Dose</th>
                    <th>Days</th>
                    <th>External Medicine</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<label for = 'docfee'>Doctor Fee</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-line">
        <input type="text" name="docFee" id="docFee" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>
<button class="btn btn-primary m-t-10 waves-effect" type="submit" name="submit">ADD PRESCRIPTION</button></form>

<script> 

    function deleteRow()
    {
        $('table').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function(e){
           $(this).closest('tr').remove()
            })
    }

        function addRow()
        {
            // get input values
            var drugName = document.getElementById('drugId').value;
            var dose = document.getElementById('dose').value;
            var days = document.getElementById('days').value;
            var eMedicine = document.getElementById('eMedicine').value;
            var action = "<input type='button' class='btn btn-danger m-t-4 waves-effect' id='del' name='del' onclick='deleteRow()' value='DELETE'>";

              // get the html table
              // 0 = the first table
              var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

              // add new empty row to the table
              // 0 = in the top 
              // table.rows.length = the end
              // table.rows.length/2+1 = the center
              var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

              // add cells to the row
              var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
              var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
              var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
              var cel4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
              var cel5 = newRow.insertCell(4);

              // add values to the cells
              cel1.innerHTML = drugName;
              cel2.innerHTML = dose;
              cel3.innerHTML = days;
              cel4.innerHTML = eMedicine;
              cel5.innerHTML = action;

              document.getElementById("drugId").value = "0";
              document.getElementById("dose").value = "";
              document.getElementById("days").value = "";
              document.getElementById("eMedicine").value = "";
        }

</script>
```

Comment: check for $_POST values (isset function), and insert them in the database with an INSERT query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use my example, i'm focus on table, and the other you can add some input or other, its make with pure javascript.

Hopefully can help you.

On first image, its a inventory for your drug store, below the image
[image: store front dashboard]

you can add, and delete the row, you cannot update theme because it maybe waste more time, just delete them if you wrong.

After this you can save medicine to database, I suggest you use PDO.

Why? because it more save(i think ^_^,), and support multiple query too. see on this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

After you sure about transaction, you can save it, and will be redirected to medicSave.php => my example. See below image for part two.
[image]

Okay for above picture, I just display the result as JSON. you can store JSON data to database directly after this, sure with QUERY ^_^.

Oh if you need a code, see on below
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../foundlose/vendor/meotip/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>List Of Medicine</h1>
    <form method="post" action="medicSave.php">
        <div class="indef">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Drug Name</th>
                        <th>Dose</th>
                        <th>Days</th>
                        <th>External Medicine</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="dataset"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="indef">
            <input type="hidden" name="totalRow" id="totalRow" value="0">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-process">Save Medicine</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <div class="indef">
        <label for="drugName"><span>Drug Name :</span>
            <input type="text" id="drugName" placeholder="Insert Drug Name">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="indef">
        <label for="dose"><span>Dose :</span>
            <input type="text" id="dose" placeholder="Insert Dose">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="indef">
        <label for="days"><span>Days :</span>
            <input type="text" id="days" placeholder="Insert Days">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="indef">
        <label for="externalMedicine"><span>External Medicine :</span>
            <input type="text" id="externalMedicine" placeholder="Insert External Medicine">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="indef">
        <button id="add" class="btn btn-info">Add medicine list</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var dataset = document.getElementById('dataset'),
    drugName = document.getElementById('drugName'),
    dose = document.getElementById('dose'),
    days = document.getElementById('days'),
    externalMedicine = document.getElementById('externalMedicine'),
    add = document.getElementById('add'),
    totalRow = document.getElementById('totalRow');

    add.onclick = function(){

        var getRow = dataset.getElementsByTagName('tr').length,
        trDataset = document.createElement('tr'),
        tdDrugName = document.createElement('td'),
        tdDose = document.createElement('td'),
        tdDays = document.createElement('td'),
        tdExternalMedicine = document.createElement('td'),
        inDrugName = document.createElement('input'),
        inDose = document.createElement('input'),
        inDays = document.createElement('input'),
        inExternalMedicine = document.createElement('input'),
        tdAction = document.createElement('td');

        /* Initiate Column Drugname Section */

        inDrugName.setAttribute('type','hidden');

        inDrugName.setAttribute('id','drugname_' + getRow);

        inDrugName.value = drugName.value;

        inDrugName.name = 'drugname_' + getRow;

        tdDrugName.textContent = drugName.value;

        tdDrugName.appendChild(inDrugName);

        /* End Column Drugname Section */

        /* Initiate Column Dose Section*/

        inDose.setAttribute('type','hidden');

        inDose.setAttribute('id','dose_' + getRow);

        inDose.value = dose.value;

        inDose.name = 'dose_' + getRow;

        tdDose.textContent = dose.value;

        tdDose.appendChild(inDose);

        /* End Column Dose Section */

        /* Initiate Column Days Section*/

        inDays.setAttribute('type','hidden');

        inDays.setAttribute('id','days_' + getRow);

        inDays.value = days.value;

        inDays.name = 'days_' + getRow;

        tdDays.textContent = days.value;

        tdDays.appendChild(inDays);

        /* End Column Days Section */

        /* Initiate Column External Medicine Section*/

        inExternalMedicine.setAttribute('type','hidden');

        inExternalMedicine.setAttribute('id','external_medicine_' + getRow);

        inExternalMedicine.value = externalMedicine.value;

        inExternalMedicine.name = 'external_medicine_' + getRow;

        tdExternalMedicine.textContent = externalMedicine.value;

        tdExternalMedicine.appendChild(inExternalMedicine);

        /* End Column External Medicine Section */

        /* Action */

        tdAction.textContent = 'Click At Row';

        /* End Action*/

        /* Initiate Each Row */

        trDataset.appendChild(tdDrugName);

        trDataset.appendChild(tdDose);

        trDataset.appendChild(tdDays);

        trDataset.appendChild(tdExternalMedicine);

        trDataset.appendChild(tdAction);

        /* Trigger To Select */

        trDataset.onclick = (function(){

            return function(){

                drugName.value = this.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

                dose.value = this.childNodes[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

                days.value = this.childNodes[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

                externalMedicine.value = this.childNodes[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

                this.parentNode.removeChild(this);

                totalRow.value = dataset.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;

                drugName.focus();

            }

        }());

        /* Add Row To Dataset / Table */

        dataset.appendChild(trDataset);

        getRow++;

        /*Set Total Row, This Use for looping in medicSave.php*/

        totalRow.value = getRow;

        /* Reset Value Input*/

        drugName.value = '';

        dose.value = '';

        days.value = '';

        externalMedicine.value = '';

        drugName.focus();

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

medicSave.php

```
<?php
//for this your can store this data to your table ^_^
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_POST,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

or run on snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
*{
 margin: 0;padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: normal;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #000000;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 font-family: "Inconsolata";
}
html, body{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
body{
 overflow-x: hidden;
 background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
h1{
 font-size: 32px;
 line-height: 40px;
}
h2{
 font-size: 30px;
 line-height: 38px;
}
h3{
 font-size: 28px;
 line-height: 36px;
}
h4{
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 34px;
}
h5{
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 32px;
}
h6{
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 30px;
}
p, span{
 display: inline;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 word-spacing: 2px;
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 24px;
}
strong{
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 24px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
hr{
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
 border-top: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #888888;
 margin: 10px 0;
}
br{
 clear: both;
}
button{
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background-color: #FAFAFA;
 border: 1px solid #888888;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 16px;
}
button.btn{
 color: #FAFAFA;
 border-color: transparent;
}
button.btn-none{
 background-color: #888888;
}
button.btn-danger{
 background-color: #F3192A;
}
button.btn-warning{
 background-color: #FB7C19;
}
button.btn-info{
 background-color: #1953F3;
}
button.btn-process{
 background-color: #2CA62B;
}
button.btn-help{
 background-color: #671E72;
}
a{
 font-size: 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #1953F3;
 cursor: pointer;
}
a.btn{
 padding: 3px 10px;
 border:1px solid transparent;
 color: #FAFAFA;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
a.btn-none{
 background-color: #888888;
}
a.btn-danger{
 background-color: #F3192A;
}
a.btn-warning{
 background-color: #FB7C19;
}
a.btn-info{
 background-color: #1953F3;
}
a.btn-process{
 background-color: #2CA62B;
}
a.btn-help{
 background-color: #671E72;
}
pre, code{
 padding: 10px;
 overflow: auto;
}
pre.code, code.code{
 border:1px solid #888888;
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #28C340;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 20px;
 max-height: 375px;
 height: auto;
 font-family: "Source Code Pro";
 tab-size:2;
}
table{
 border:1px solid #888888;
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr, td, th{
 border:1px solid #888888;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 font-size: 16px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
tr:hover{
 background-color: #000000;
}
tr:hover td, tr:hover th{
 color: #FAFAFA;
}
tr:nth-child(even){
 background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
tr:nth-child(even):hover{
 background-color: #000000;
}
th{
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}
/**/
.container{
 max-width: 800px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0 10px;
 display: block;
 margin: auto auto;
}
.indef{
 padding: 5px 0;
}
.indef label{
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.indef input{
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #888888;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}
.indef select, .indef option{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #1953F3;
 color: #FAFAFA;
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.indef textarea{
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #888888;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 height: 400px;
 resize: none;
} 
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <h1>List Of Medicine</h1>
 <form method="post" action="medicSave.php">
  <div class="indef">
   <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Drug Name</th>
      <th>Dose</th>
      <th>Days</th>
      <th>External Medicine</th>
      <th>Action</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="dataset"></tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div class="indef">
   <input type="hidden" name="totalRow" id="totalRow" value="0">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-process">Save Medicine</button>
  </div>
 </form>
 <hr>
 <div class="indef">
  <label for="drugName"><span>Drug Name :</span>
   <input type="text" id="drugName" placeholder="Insert Drug Name">
  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="indef">
  <label for="dose"><span>Dose :</span>
   <input type="text" id="dose" placeholder="Insert Dose">
  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="indef">
  <label for="days"><span>Days :</span>
   <input type="text" id="days" placeholder="Insert Days">
  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="indef">
  <label for="externalMedicine"><span>External Medicine :</span>
   <input type="text" id="externalMedicine" placeholder="Insert External Medicine">
  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="indef">
  <button id="add" class="btn btn-info">Add medicine list</button>
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var dataset = document.getElementById('dataset'),
 drugName = document.getElementById('drugName'),
 dose = document.getElementById('dose'),
 days = document.getElementById('days'),
 externalMedicine = document.getElementById('externalMedicine'),
 add = document.getElementById('add'),
 totalRow = document.getElementById('totalRow');

 add.onclick = function(){

  var getRow = dataset.getElementsByTagName('tr').length,
  trDataset = document.createElement('tr'),
  tdDrugName = document.createElement('td'),
  tdDose = document.createElement('td'),
  tdDays = document.createElement('td'),
  tdExternalMedicine = document.createElement('td'),
  inDrugName = document.createElement('input'),
  inDose = document.createElement('input'),
  inDays = document.createElement('input'),
  inExternalMedicine = document.createElement('input'),
  tdAction = document.createElement('td');

  /* Initiate Column Drugname Section */

  inDrugName.setAttribute('type','hidden');

  inDrugName.setAttribute('id','drugname_' + getRow);

  inDrugName.value = drugName.value;

  inDrugName.name = 'drugname_' + getRow;

  tdDrugName.textContent = drugName.value;

  tdDrugName.appendChild(inDrugName);

  /* End Column Drugname Section */

  /* Initiate Column Dose Section*/

  inDose.setAttribute('type','hidden');

  inDose.setAttribute('id','dose_' + getRow);

  inDose.value = dose.value;

  inDose.name = 'dose_' + getRow;

  tdDose.textContent = dose.value;

  tdDose.appendChild(inDose);

  /* End Column Dose Section */

  /* Initiate Column Days Section*/

  inDays.setAttribute('type','hidden');

  inDays.setAttribute('id','days_' + getRow);

  inDays.value = days.value;

  inDays.name = 'days_' + getRow;

  tdDays.textContent = days.value;

  tdDays.appendChild(inDays);

  /* End Column Days Section */

  /* Initiate Column External Medicine Section*/

  inExternalMedicine.setAttribute('type','hidden');

  inExternalMedicine.setAttribute('id','external_medicine_' + getRow);

  inExternalMedicine.value = externalMedicine.value;

  inExternalMedicine.name = 'external_medicine_' + getRow;

  tdExternalMedicine.textContent = externalMedicine.value;

  tdExternalMedicine.appendChild(inExternalMedicine);

  /* End Column External Medicine Section */

  /* Action */

  tdAction.textContent = 'Click At Row';

  /* End Action*/

  /* Initiate Each Row */

  trDataset.appendChild(tdDrugName);

  trDataset.appendChild(tdDose);

  trDataset.appendChild(tdDays);

  trDataset.appendChild(tdExternalMedicine);

  trDataset.appendChild(tdAction);

  /* Trigger To Select */

  trDataset.onclick = (function(){

   return function(){

    drugName.value = this.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

    dose.value = this.childNodes[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

    days.value = this.childNodes[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

    externalMedicine.value = this.childNodes[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);

    totalRow.value = dataset.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;

    drugName.focus();

   }

  }());

  /* Add Row To Dataset / Table */

  dataset.appendChild(trDataset);

  getRow++;

  /*Set Total Row, This Use for looping in medicSave.php*/

  totalRow.value = getRow;

  /* Reset Value Input*/

  drugName.value = '';

  dose.value = '';

  days.value = '';

  externalMedicine.value = '';

  drugName.focus();

 }
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```